# How to create a sequence of dates with SQL that start with "select" and does not use default Tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select

So I'm trying to create a sequence of dates in SQL, but I have some limitations for the script:
1. It must start with "select".
2. It can't use recursion. 
3. It can't use default Tables.

The reason for this is that it will not run in MSSQL but in a BI Tool, Which has SQL-like syntax but much more limited.

I found these solutions already:

```
WITH CTE_DatesTable
AS
(
SELECT CAST('2013-05-20' as datetime) AS [date]
UNION ALL
SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, [date])
FROM CTE_DatesTable
WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, [date]) <= '2016-10-18'
)
SELECT date FROM CTE_DatesTable
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);
```

And this :

```
select  dateadd(day, number, '2014-1-1')
from 
(select distinct number from master.dbo.spt_values
 where name is null
) n
where dateadd(day, number, '2014-1-1') < '2017-1-1'
```

But both violate the limitations so I can't use them. I thought about using the second one and create a table with the columns "number" and "name" just like in the "master.dbo.spt_values" but this script will have to be with the same limitations, so I'm pretty much back to the original problem.

Comment: What does "must start with select" mean? And if you are using a non standard query language, how are we supposed to guess what will or won't work?

Comment: "Must start with Select" means that the BI tool (SiSense) won't except any query that starts with something else. 
it's not a different language, just a very limited version of regular SQL. 
I know it's not very helpful but that's what I have to work it, sorry.

Comment: The solution I've seen most often that's disappointing but really easy is to just create a table with all dates within range of feasible need. For all dates in 32 bit Unix time range (1970–2038) the table would have ~25,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try generating a table with a list of your dates and then selecting all values from this table, using loop logic such as the below.

declare @date = 'yyyy-mm-dd' date

create table #temp (date_seq date)

while @date <= 'yyyy-mm-dd'

insert into #temp values (@date)

@date = DATE_ADD(dd, 1, @date)

end

select * from #temp